# How to deal with "+FTPOPEN: 2" response from gprs module

Tags: ftp, at-command, gprs

I am trying to connect to ftp server from gprs module. But `ftpopen?` command   returning error message`+ftpopen: 2` to which I couldn't find any description in google and don't know any idea how to solve it.

Here is a sample of commands which I'm sending.

```
at+mipcall=1,"internet.beeline.uz"\r
at+ftpopen="demo.wftpserver.com","demo-user","demo-user",,,,\r
at+ftpopen?\r
```

Did anybody here meet this problem before?

**Device**
model: G610,
version: Q50-00,
manufacturer: fibocom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

Find the exact model name and version number of your gprs module. Make a note of it for yourself and also update the question with this information because it is extremely important background information.

Step 2:

Find the official AT command documentation corresponding to your gprs module. The manufacturer ought to have them available on their web site.

Step 3:

Read the documentation you got.

This is the general way to deal with problems like that. For commands that are standardized by 3GPP (like AT+CPBR etc) you might get away with just reading the standard document, however manufacturers do not necessarily comply 100% and lots of commands are optional, so the only authoritative document is the official manufacturer's AT command documentation for the given modem.

None of the commands you list are standardized by 3GPP so the only reliable source of information is the official AT command documentation from the manufacturer corresponding to your gprs module. You really, really, really should get hold of this. Call them, email them or write snail mail to them if you do not find it. Ask the shop you bought it from. Ask again if you do not get it. And again and again if you still do not get it. You do need this document.